# Migrating to something not in the list

Tags: support, migration

When I vote to migrate a question, I get presented with about five options for targets. Usually none of them are the right one.

Is there a way to choose a different migration target than those listed? I'm sure there must be, I'm probably just missing it!

Comment: Flag the question for a moderator to migrate

Answer (score 3):

If the following two conditions are met then flag for moderator attention using the "other" option.

1. The question is a **good** question. Migration is not the way to get rid of bad questions from your site.
2. The question is **really** off topic for your site. There are a number of sites that have overlaps with each other. Just because it's on topic for one site doesn't necessarily make it off topic for your site.

Additionally, it will probably help if you are an active member with a "reasonable" reputation of the site you want the question migrating to. This shows us you have an understanding of the target's site scope and audience.

If these conditions aren't met then deal with the question on the site it's currently on.